# Does c++/Arduino handle '?' differently compared with other chars

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, arduino

I have an Android app that is communicating with and arduino board via bluetooth

All the commands are going backward and forwards fine, until I wanted to send a comand of the type

```
"aT?bb"
```

from the android app, however when I print it in ardunio I am getting

```
"aT%3F"
```

I am logging the command in android and it is formed correctly My quesion is does c++/Arduino handle '?' differently then normal chars?

here is my arduino code->

```
while(bluetooth.available())
{
char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read();
if(toSend != '\0'){
    if (toSend == 'a'){ i=0 ;}
    inMsg[i] = toSend;
    i++;
  } 
}
if(i == 5 )
{
// mock sending queries
  if(inMsg[2] == '?'){
   if(inMsg[1] == 'T'){
      bluetooth.write("ty1");Serial.println("");
    }else if(inMsg[1] == 'x'){  //normal cycle
       bluetooth.write("xx1");
    }else if(inMsg[1] == 'X'){ Serial.println(""); //booter
       bluetooth.write("XX0");
    }else if(inMsg[1] == 'N'){Serial.println("");  //On time 
       bluetooth.write("on1");
    }else if(inMsg[1] == 'F'){ Serial.println(""); //Off time
       bluetooth.write("of30");
    }else if(inMsg[1] == 'S'){ Serial.println(""); //Speed percent
       bluetooth.write("sp30");
    }
}
// write to console 
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    Serial.write(inMsg[j]);
}
// new line
  if(i == 5){Serial.println("");}
  i = 0; // reset buffer
}


aT%3F <- this is mal formed
aS133 <- all the other are as I sent them from android 
aN169
aF192
aS200
aXXXX
aYYYY
ayYYY
axXXX
```

my Android Code
     ...
     command = "aT?bb";
     writeCommand(command);
     ...

```
private void writeCommand(String command)
{
    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics)
    {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) >0)
        {
            try {
                characteristic.setValue(URLEncoder.encode(command, "utf-8"));
                gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 0x3F is the ASCII code of `?`.   It's quite likely that the conversion from the character to an escape sequence is happening on the Android side, perhaps where you attempt to turn a Java String into a bunch of bytes to put through the BT connection, or something like that.  Including your Android code would be a big help.

Comment: it is the URLEncoder isnt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above it was the URLEncoder that was changing the String. I have now changed this method to

```
private void writeCommand(String command)
{
    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics)
    {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) >0)
        {
            characteristic.setValue(command);
            gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"non write able");
        }
    }
}
```